# Sendmail sending local

Tags: linux, email, centos, sendmail, mail-server

So, I have no idea how to begin solving this, I'm very unfamiliar with Sendmail.

I have a server, domain "example.com", and in the mx records we have a domain "example.com" if we have the server send email to "bob@example.com" then it tries to send it to a local user called bob, who doesn't exist, instead of forwarding it exrernaly to the domain bob@example.com

Is this the intended behaviour, if so, how can I overwrite this. If not, where might I have gone wrong in setup?